# UIView background color affects touches in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uikit

I had a custom view with subclassed touch responses that was working in iOS 4. On iOS 5, these touches would not respond at all when touched along the bottom edge of the view, *if* the view's background color was set to `clearColor`.

I have not been able to track this down, but does anyone know if iOS 5 changed the way views respond to touches depending on a transparent background?

I can make no changes to the code other than set the background color to any opaque color like `orangeColor` and the view fully responds.

Note the issue does not affect touches elsewhere in the view; only along the bottom edge, anywhere below the last subview added to the view; presumably a clear background is treated as if the view does not exist for the sake of touches when looking at an area of the view that has no content. Change the color, the view has "content" and the touches work!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using `[UIColor clearColor]`, try using this:

```
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.1]];
```

**NOTE**: A `UIView` does not respond to touch events when the `alpha` is anything below `0.1`. `[UIColor clearColor]` sets an `alpha` to `0.0`, so you won't get the touch events. Following the above method, you can receive the touch events on a transparent view.

Comment: nice suggestion but makes no difference

Comment: Touches are ignored when the alpha value is less than `0.1`. Try setting it to `0.1`. If this works I will edit my answer to reflect that

Comment: my view has an alpha of 1.0; it is visible and its subviews are visible, but the background color is `clearColor`

Comment: I know, set the alpha on the UIColor, from my posted answer to 0.1. I don't mean the alpha on the view itself..

Comment: wow! that did the trick. please update your answer and I will accept it. thanks!

Comment: It seems at least with iOS 8 that touch events are triggered with alpha set to 0.01, no longer does it need to be 0.1.

Comment: Problem is, even alpha at 0.01 affects how the view **looks**, so it's not a good solution. What kind of weird optimization is this, anyway? It seems to bypass hitTest entirely. I even tried adding an extra subview to the transparent subview — itself also transparent — and hitTest wasn't triggered even then. I guess it's reading the actual pixel values of the rendered view before performing any hit detection? Why isn't this behavior described in the documentation?!

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else runs into this problem and wants a better solution than setting a partial opacity for the background, you can set the view's `opaque` property to `NO` and then add an empty `drawRect:` method. (Tested and working on iOS8, beta 4.)

Comment: This is a great solution that works is most scenarios. Works for me in both iOS 7.1.2 & iOS 8.1.3.

Comment: This also causes your view's layout to use an astronomical amount of memory.